# IIS allowing 3/4 identical Ajax calls

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis

Running in IIS Express, none of these issues exist, it is only using release IIS where this becomes an issue.

I have 4 Ajax calls to retrieve data from the server, they are all identical. One of them refuses to work, claiming that

```
This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.
```

This is incorrect, all functions returning data are returning data as follows:

```
return Json(clients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The Ajax calls all look like this:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: './Updater/getClientsInfo',
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {
        clientinfo = response;
        processUpdate();
    }
});
```

I believe it is a configuration issue as it was working fine until I came back in today.

Edit:

I disabled IIS on this machine and re-enabled it and I'm getting Windows errors while trying to enable Windows features, so there's obviously something going on with this Windows install. I'll have to troubleshoot that first as I suspect the code itself may be unrelated.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The error message notes a `GET` that you have an `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` and then say the call look like a `POST`? Somehow I doubt that is correct for what you post.

Comment: These calls have never been changed and has been working for 6+ months. As I said the only situation it doesn't work in is in the last 2 hours, on IIS release, and 1 of 4 Ajax calls.

Comment: Have you been using IIS release for the whole 6 months and regularly testing this? While I suspect there may be a web.config issue here, I'm not sure you understand the point of my first comment here.

Comment: I understand, its just not what I'm asking about, and I noticed a lot of people going down irrelevant paths of troubleshooting when answering questions on this website. Anyway, yes, if this ajax call had ever stopped working in the last 6 months, many people would have noticed **instantly**.

Comment: Is there some way to just completely refresh/reset/default IIS?

Comment: You could uninstall and reinstall IIS within Windows Server, sure. Don't forget to run the "aspnet_regiis" command so that ASP.Net is connected to IIS properly.

Comment: Looks like things are working now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute via a GET request and have an error handler set up to catch errors but forget to allow GET requests inside the catch, you'll get this error as well.  I just ran into this where I had the following

```
 public JsonResult GetCustomer(string id) {
        try { 
            var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();
            return this.Json(new JsonMessage(true, customerRepository.GetCustomer(id)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogException(ex);
            return this.Json(new JsonMessage(false, ex.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

The problem was in the catch.  Without the following, the server would prevent the error from being sent back

```
return this.Json(new JsonMessage(false, ex.ToString()), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: That could actually be the real answer. We would need to see @Yelnick controller and error handling.

Comment: Although I was having IIS issues, turns out they were likely independent of this issue, and your solution is correct. Someone had added a rogue key to the database that was returning "The given key was not present in the dictionary." I had forgot to AllowGet on the error as well. Thanks